# What does the 'el' do in view.render().el?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I am trying to learn backbone.  I understand that `el` is the element that is being acted on.  If it isnt specified it is an empty div.  I am creating a template inside my view and returning the view object.  I am then rendering the view, but I dont understand why I chain `el` after the render function.  Could someone please explain this line of code to me:

```
var view = new PersonView();
this.$('#family_list').children().append(view.render().el);
```

What is the el for?  Thanks.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

jQuery's [`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) method expects a string of HTML or a DOM element to be appended to its calling node.

The [`.el`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-el) property of the view is its bound DOM element.  After calling `view.render()`, its `.el` DOM element property is passed into the jQuery `.append()` method, so jQuery `.append()` gets the updated (newly rendered) DOM node.

This is made possible because the `.render()` call must be returning `this` [as suggested in the documentation](http://backbonejs.org/#View-render).  Its return value is therefore the view object itself<sup>1</sup>, and from that the `.el` can be referenced immediately.

---

<sup>1</sup> Wikipedia: [Fluent interfaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface)